# Finding rows which match the average value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, average, aggregate-functions

I'm using Oracle 11g. I have a couple of tables which look something like this (simplified a bit).

```
CREATE TABLE clients (
    id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    gridx NUMBER(10),
    gridy NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT clients_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE requests (
    id NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    client_id NUMBER(10),
    CONSTRAINT clients_fk FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES clients(id),
    CONSTRAINT requests_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I need to find the grid sections which have seen the average number of requests. So far, I have come up with the following query which lists the number of requests made for each distinct grid location.

```
SELECT joined_tbl.gridx, joined_tbl.gridy, COUNT(joined_tbl.id) requests_cnt FROM (
    SELECT c.gridx, c.gridy, r.id
    FROM requests r
    INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id=r.client_id GROUP BY c.gridx, c.gridy, r.id ORDER BY r.id
) joined_tbl
GROUP BY joined_tbl.gridx, joined_tbl.gridy;
```

This gives the following output

> ```
>  GRIDX      GRIDY REQUESTS_CNT
>      1         -3            2
>      2          5            4
>     -1         -3            4
>     -3         -2            6
> ```

Next I need to take the average of the REQUESTS_CNT column and list all the rows which match the average value. How can I go about this? I can't use the AVG function in a WHERE clause, which I considered, so should I be using HAVING?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Isn't your query just an inflated `SELECT c.gridx, c.gridy, COUNT(*) AS requests_cnt FROM requests r INNER JOIN clients c ON c.id = r.client_id GROUP BY c.gridx, c.gridy`? And then what is your expected result? You want the average of the request count, which is 4 in your example. And then you want all gridx/gridy that have a count of 4? So, you want the result to be (2|5), (-1|-3)? Is this correct? If so, what if the counts were 2, 2, 4, 4? The average would be 3. No x|y with a count of 3, so no result?

Comment: If there's no result that would be fine I assume. It's just the task I've been given. Thank you for showing me a greatly simplified version of this. I have a lot to learn about SQL and I tie myself in knots coming up with the query it seems. Still, I need to calculate the average, even if no rows are returned.

Comment: Also yes,  (2|5), (-1|-3) would be the correct result in this case.

Comment: Okay. I suppose in 99% of the cases you'll get no rows at all. An average can be any fraction (0.5, 5.33333, whatever), and even if the average happens to be an integer, that count may not exist (as in my example of average = 3). I've posted an answer. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query can be boiled down to:

```
SELECT c.gridx, c.gridy, COUNT(*) AS requests_cnt
FROM requests r 
JOIN clients c ON c.id = r.client_id 
GROUP BY c.gridx, c.gridy;
```

i.e. get the request count per gridx/gridy. You want to determine the average count and then only show gridx/gridy pairs that occur exactly that often. In your example this would be the pairs (2|5), (-1|-3), but most often, I guess, that would be no pairs at all.

The easiest approach seems to be to get the average on-the-fly by applying `AVG OVER`:

```
SELECT gridx, gridy
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    c.gridx, c.gridy, COUNT(*) AS requests_cnt,
    AVG(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS avg_requests_cnt
  FROM requests r 
  JOIN clients c ON c.id = r.client_id 
  GROUP BY c.gridx, c.gridy
) pairs
WHERE requests_cnt = avg_requests_cnt
ORDER BY gridx, gridy;
```

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but you already got there... [here is the db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f53a4eeb34fbd1d75a020be96e4e9213).

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful answer. Thank you, and to anyone who also wanted to help.

Comment: Why don't you accept that answer, then, @denormal?

Comment: Apologies. That's done.